# My css -jquery drop down menu is overlapping by table th tag

Tags: jquery, css

drop down menu is just like ul list menu---

```
<li> <a href="#"><span> My Daashboard &nbsp; <em class="opener-technology"> <img src="../images/zonebar-downarrow.png" alt="dropdown" /> 
  </em> </span></a> 
  <ul class="technologysublist">
    <li><a href="#">Apple</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Design</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Gadgets</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Hardware</a></li>     
  </ul>
</li>
```

The above drop down menu list is hidden because of the html td tag ..can you tell me how to solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

why don't you use increase the z-index value of technologysublist

```
.technologysublist{
postion:absolute;
z-index:1; //1 or greater till it comes up
}
```